# How to render the HTML from ckeditor with the same styles

Tags: html, css, ckeditor4.x

Recently I started a project which uses ckeditor. Everything worked fine until I tried to show the text I entered, I couldn't show the page with the same style as it had when I was typing in the `textarea`. I also tried to use the contents.css file in the ckeditor folder that did not help. So if there is anything I should try out or must explain please feel free to say it. Here is what's happening.

---

This is how I wrote it and it is looking fine in the `textarea` replaced by ckeditor.
[image: This is how I wrote]

But when I saved it and render it to the page the text loses its styles.
[image: This is how it looks when rendered to screen]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to render the same contents and styles from CKEditor.
First one is to convert the ckeditor inline styles to public html styles. But I don't think it's ideal.
The best way is to put another inline ckeditor(which doesn't have any toolbars, outlines and etc) and then render the contents inside of it.

`https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/inline.html`